# using an editable cell in a kendo grid with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-2.0

need help about integration of knockout.js with kendo grid

when i change the text in an editable field, in a kendo grid, I need to change at the same time an html tag... just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#b").attr("data-bind", "value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'");
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});

function AppViewModel() {
this.lastName = ko.observable();
}
```

---

```
 <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>
    Last name:
    <input id="b" />
</p>
```

i do not have idea how to do it...

an example or any help would be very appreciated!!!!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to use knockout.js, just add the following function:

```
 function editk(e) {    
     var ddl = e.container.find(".k-input").focus();
```

ddl.keydown(function (e) {
       
          });
     }

And in the grid definition add

```
   edit: editk
```

in this way,  you can handle the keydown event in the edit bix of the grid

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can take the edited item using the [save](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-save) event,

```
var appModel=new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(appModel);

$('#grid').kendoGrid({
.....
 save:function(e){
      var item=e.model;
      appModel.lastName(item.lastName);
    }
})
```

Comment: hi and thanks for your reply, I need to update the dom element on the keypress or keydown, not on the save method of the grid. Hope you can help me!!